# Is there a way to output static files from a Ruby on Rails build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm finishing up a build of a rails site and the requirements of the project have changed. Rather than a hosted rails site, I am now to deliver the site as static files. Short of viewing each page's source, saving it out, and adjusting the head file references, is there a gem or a plugin of sorts that can help me output this as static html/css/js files?

Standard rails 5 build. More or less out of the box.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing is the site is dynamic? None of the content is created by users? Rails favors convention over configuration and this new requirement is definitely outside of that convention, I would be surprised if there is something out here within Rails to help you out. I'm sure a site crawler of sorts will do the trick from the outside (think of it as an automated browser that visits each page, downloads the source, follows each link inside and repeats)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't have any luck finding a simple gem since this is such an unusual use-case for rails. Your best bet is to use a web crawler which visits all of your pages for you and saves them. A simple way to 'download' the site is with wget:

```
wget --convert-links --mirror example.com
```

This blog post [details the entire process](https://thepugautomatic.com/2014/08/archiving-rails/), from crawling your rails site to hosting it statically; it may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for this. Obviously this isn't the ideal use case for what should have been a pretty straight forward build, but this definitely got me through what I needed.  Appreciate the help.